# undeclared identifier SQL_SS_TABLE

Tags: c++, sql-server-2012, odbc, table-valued-parameters

I would like to work with Table valued parameter in C++ using ODBC. There are many interssting samples for working with TVPs with ODBC. For example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510470.aspx)

A very nice function is [SQLbinparameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms710963(v=vs.85).aspx). From [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522485.aspx) for Table Valued parameter this function should be looked like this:

```
r = SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 
    2,// ParameterNumber
    SQL_PARAM_INPUT,// InputOutputType
    SQL_C_DEFAULT,// ValueType 
    SQL_SS_TABLE,// Parametertype
    ITEM_ARRAY_SIZE,// ColumnSize: For a table-valued parameter this is the row array size.
    0,// DecimalDigits: For a table-valued parameter this is always 0. 
    TVP,// ParameterValuePtr: For a table-valued parameter this is the type name of the 
//table-valued parameter, and also a token returned by SQLParamData.
    SQL_NTS,// BufferLength: For a table-valued parameter this is the length of the type name or SQL_NTS.
    &cbTVP);// StrLen_or_IndPtr: For a table-valued parameter this is the number of rows actually use
```

But I recieve the error: `error C2065: SQL_SS_TABLE undeclared identifier`

what should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am going to guess that you are attempting to use this feature on Linux, and the most popular linux ODBC package (unixODBC) simply does not support this feature.

There is a chance if you use the official Microsoft driver (Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server on Linux) this feature will be supported.

Answer (score 2):

It is a driver specific type, requiring the respective driver's SDK installation and header inclusion. It defines `SQL_SS_TABLE` together with other newer SQL Server specific types.

**Edit November 2022:**

Microsoft has begun deprecating the ODBC Native Client and recommends switching to the [Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server). Using these SDKs, the include directory now changes to:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\VERSION\SDK\Include

VERSION to be replaced by the installed driver version, the current newest one is 180 for "Microsoft ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server". The header file for this driver is **msodbcsql.h**

**Old Answer:**

SQL Server examples use the Native Client's **sqlncli.h** header file located at

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Include

Credits to "Viorel_" for originally answering this question on the MSDN forums: [Using new ODBC sql data typ SQL_SS_TABLE in c++](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/65231151-ca40-447f-8d59-02a297dfe5df/)